# How to shorten multiple if statements (not if else)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array in which i want to conditionally push some values. Is there a cleaner way of doing this (code below)?

```
const pushedValues = []; 
if (someArray[0].value) {
    pushedValues.push(x);
}
if (someArray[1].value) {
    pushedValues.push(y);
}
if (someArray[2].value) {
    pushedValues.push(z);
}
...
```

Comment: If the values in `someArray` and `x`, `y`, `z` don't have any connection to each other. No, you can't. If you can determine `x` `y` and `y` with the help of the respective value (or index) in `someArray` you can use a loop.

Comment: Use a loop! (And store `x`, `y` and `z` in an array, too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the values `x, y, z` into an array and loop over the values with the index.

```js
const pushedValues = []; 
[x, y, z].forEach((val, i)=>{
    if(someArray[i].value) pushedValues.push(val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a forEach like this

```
const pushedValues = []; 
const data = [x, y, z]
someArray.forEach((v, i) => {
 v.value && pushedValues.push(data[i])
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You are working with the `someArray` array. You must first check the values inside an iterative control ( `for` or `while` ) and then use the `switch-case` construct.